# How to trigger "BadImageFormatException'?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to create a "BadimageFormatException" in my local to test some cacheing issue. How to create "BadImageFormatException"?

Comment: `var ex = new BadImageFormatException();`

Comment: Umm, how about the documentation for BadImageFormatException: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.badimageformatexception?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 2):

As already specified in the comments, you can just create and throw this exception:

```
throw new BadImageFormatException();
```

If you want to cause this exception **naturally**, then as per [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.badimageformatexception?view=netframework-4.7.2),

> This exception is thrown when the file format of a dynamic link library (.dll file) or an executable (.exe file) doesn't conform to the format that the common language runtime expects

It means that you can cause it by trying to load an invalid assembly file:

```
string tempPath = Path.GetTempFileName();

using (var file = File.OpenWrite(tempPath))
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(file))
{
    sw.WriteLine("I am not an assembly");
}

Assembly.LoadFile(tempPath);
```

Thanks to **@Xiaoy312** for the advice. There is a much simpler way to do this using `Assembly.Load`:

```
Assembly.Load(new byte[] { 0 });
```

Comment: Even shorter: `Assembly.Load(new byte[] { 0 })`

Answer (score 0):

If new to this, then one way also is to load an unmanaged assembly for example notepad.exe.

```
try
    {
        // path to notepad.exe.
        string path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%windir%") + @"\System32\notepad.exe";
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(path);
    }
    catch (System.BadImageFormatException exception)
    {
       // catch an exception.
    }
```

As Notepad is unmanaged and not compiled with .Net, .net isnt very happy and throws the exception.

For interesting trivia, `BadImageFormatException` has nothing to do with bad image format like `gifs` or `jpegs` but its an exception when .Net attempts to load a `DLL` or `exe` which isnt compatible with CLR.

Also, all exceptions are derived from [System.Exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception?view=netframework-4.7.2). `BadImageFormatException` is just inherited from `System.Exception`.